# Getting Page not found error on MVC4 IIS6

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I wanted to Host my Web Application Built in ASP.NET MVC 4 in .NET 4 on Windows Server 2003 IIS6. I followed some steps given in [This Blog (haacked.com)](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx/). I followed the IIS6 Extension-less URLs approach. But the problem is, I am getting Page not found error:

[image]

I have been searching for 2 days now. Every solution redirects me to this approach. Can anyone guide me if there is any other solution or is there anything missing in the current solution?

Comment: If you go to your application in IIS and click the browse link in the right pane, do you still have the 404?

Comment: Yes unfortunately, Same error.

Comment: I like to use the web deployment extension for IIS to deploy (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy). Simply publish your application package in visual studio and import it with the import button in IIS then. Maybe it works better by doing this workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I solved it, May be in future it will be helpful to someone. I was using 64 bit version so for 64 bit version, the file `aspnet_isapi.dll` should be referenced from:

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll**

Answer (score 0):

The instructions on the page you linked seem outdated, it uses an `.mvc` extension but that was changed to 'no extension' after the early preview/beta version that was being used back then.

Instead of using `.mvc` you should leave the extension **empty** (or enter just a period if you can't leave it empty), and then **uncheck** the "Verify that file exists" checkbox.

Reference: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-integrating-asp-net-security-with-classic-asp-and-non-asp-net-urls

Comment: I did the same which is mentioned in your link, In my link, both the approaches are used, .MVC and Extension Less as well.